# why can't I directly call a method of an instance which is accessed by pointer-to-member

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

For example I got a inner class:

```
struct Foo {
  void test() {}
};
```

and a outer class:

```
struct Bar {
  Foo foo;
};
```

then in `main()`:

```
  Bar bar{};
  Foo Bar::* pFoo = &Bar::foo;

  bar.*pFoo.test(); // does not work

  Foo foo = bar.*pFoo;
  foo.test(); // works;
```

the error about `bar.*pFoo.test()` is:`member reference base type 'Foo Bar::*' is not a structure or union`, so what's the different between `bar.*pFoo.test();` and `Foo foo = bar.*pFoo; foo.test();`?

Comment: [Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The function call ranks higher than the dereference.

Comment: @BoBTFish thanks, I really didn't know the precedence of pointer-to-member before

Answer (score 3):

As hinted at in the comments, `.*` has lower operator precedence than `.`.

Thus `bar.*pFoo.test();` is parsed as `bar.*(pFoo.test());` and is trying to access the `test` member of `pFoo`.

Since `pFoo` is a member pointer of type `Foo Bar::*` this is not a valid expression. Only class-types can appear on the left-hand side of the member access operator `.` (pseudo-destructor call syntax aside), which a member pointer is not.

The second example is equivalent to the expression `(bar.*pFoo).test();` instead.